# I need to get the Dataset from SQL from Table Valued Function using code C# in visual studio

Tags: c#

1. I have a Table In SQL.
2. Then I have created one Table-Valued Function named GetTaxDataSet. So when I execute that function with the Where condition, I'm getting the dataset values that I need.
3. Now, I'm trying to get the dataset using the SQL Table-Valued function using C# code.

   ```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        string sqlSelect = "Select * From [dbo].[fn_GetTaxRuleDataSet] (@TaxID, @TaxRulesID)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, Sqlconn);

        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();

        param1.ParameterName = "@ID";
        param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

        param1.ParameterName = "@TaxID";
        param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

        param1.ParameterName = "TaxRulesID";
        param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

        param1.ParameterName = "@EffectiveDate";
        param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        Sqlconn.Open();

         //Executing The SqlCommand.
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        Console.ReadLine();
   ```

Can you guys suggest me with right code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked. This is for the Table-Valued Function. Trying to retrieve the Data from c#.

public void fn_GetTaxCalculationDataSet(int cur_tax_calc_ruleid)
{
Sqlconn.Open();      //Connection Open

```
        //Variables to Store Result from DataSet

        int TaxCalcRuleID              = cur_tax_calc_ruleid;
        int ScheduleTypeID             = 0;
        int FilingStatusID             = 0;
        int bottomorder                = 0;
        decimal bottom                 = 0;
        decimal Amount                 = 0;
        decimal plusAmountOfPercentage = 0;

        try
        {
            //Defining The Query.
            string sqlSelect = "Select * From dbo.[fn_GetTaxCalculationDataSet] (@TaxCalcRuleID)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, Sqlconn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxCalcRuleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cur_tax_calc_ruleid;

            //Executing The SqlCommand
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Retrieving CalcData based on TaxRuleID From database..!" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Retriving The Records");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key To Continue.....!");
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Check if have any records..!
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    TaxCalcRuleID  = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    ScheduleTypeID = dr.GetInt32(1);
                    FilingStatusID = dr.GetInt32(2);
                    bottomorder    = dr.GetInt32(3);
                    bottom         = dr.GetDecimal(4);
                    Amount         = dr.GetDecimal(5);
                    plusAmountOfPercentage = dr.GetDecimal(6);

                    //Displaying The Retrieved Records or DataSet..!
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}", TaxCalcRuleID.ToString(), ScheduleTypeID, FilingStatusID, bottomorder, bottom, Amount, plusAmountOfPercentage);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Close");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Data Found");
            }
            //Data ReaderClosed.
            dr.Close();

            //SQL Connection Closed. 
            Sqlconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope this answer helps you. Just keep in mind that when you create a method with its return type of DataSet, it should also be set to receive the DataSet.

```
public DataSet GetData()
{
    DataSet output = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
        }

        String sqlSelect = "Select * From [dbo].[fn_GetTaxRuleDataSet] (@TaxID, @TaxRulesID)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


        adapter.Fill(output);
        sqlConn.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                   "ServerControlScript", ex.Message, true);

        return (null);

    }
     return output;
}
```